# How do I get the differences between two string arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

How to compare two array string using C#.net?
Eg:

```
string[] com1 = { "COM6", "COM7" };
string[] com2 = { "COM6", "COM7","COM8" };
```

Here com1 and com2 are Array string.
Result:
COM8.
How to achieve this?

Comment: It would really help if you'd give more specifics about the comparison you want to make. For example, do you regard order as important? Case? What about if an element occurs in `com1` but not `com2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this the shortest way to solve this

```
foreach (string com in com2 )
{
    if (!com1.Contains(com))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(com);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 57):

Sounds like you want everything in `array2` *except* what's in `array1`:

```
var onlyInArray2 = array2.Except(array1);
```

Of course, if you *also* wanted to know what was only in `array1` you could use:

```
var onlyInArray1 = array1.Except(array2);
```

(This all requires .NET 3.5 or higher, or an alternative LINQ to Objects implementation such as LINQBridge.)

I'm assuming that order isn't important when computing differences - `Except` is a set-based operator, so assumes that you're regarding the collections as sets.

Note that `Except` just returns an `IEnumerable<T>` - if you want the results as arrays, you'll need to call `ToArray`:

```
var onlyInArray2 = array2.Except(array1).ToArray();
var onlyInArray1 = array1.Except(array2).ToArray();
```

If you want the symmetric difference, i.e. you only care about which values are in a single array, rather than which array they came from, you could use:

```
var onlyInOneArray = array1.Union(array2).Except(array1.Intersect(array2));
```

or you could use `HashSet` directly:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(array1);
// This modifies the set...
set.SymmetricExceptWith(array2);
```

In all of these, the resulting order is undefined, although in practice `Except` will preserve the original order of the first argument. While this is strictly speaking an implementation detail, I think it's very unlikely to change.

Like the other set-based operators in LINQ, `Except` will only return any element once - so if `COM8` appeared twice in `array2`, it would only appear once in the result.

Comment: His Majesty Jon, adds ever something more ;-)

Comment: I think that with your better answers here you could write another Book ... I will buy it for sure !

Answer (score 19):

Using the Linq [Except extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> result = com2.Except(com1); 
// result: { "COM8" }
```

Comment: Suggestion: change `result` to `except` (or the other way around)

Answer (score 10):

You could use [IEnumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you want everything that's in one list but not both, in a single expression, you could use [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union), [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect) *and* [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779):

```
var inOnlyOneArray = array1.Union(array2).Except(array1.Intersect(array2));
```

Comment: +, that one is smart!

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, the `Except` extension method is definitely the way to go here. I will add, however, that it looks like you might want some control over how the comparisons are made; if 'COM8' refers to a serial port identifier, then you'd want to perform a case-insensitive comparison:

```
var result = com2.Except(com1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```