# Compare two json array in c# and get only the difference in separate object

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, json.net

I am trying to compare two Json array and get only the changes or difference in the array. idea is to insert only the new records to the Database.

The belwo implementation based on the below links

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29044077/Compare-to-json-string-in-c-and-get-results.html

https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/17b9432

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string newData = string.Empty;
JObject newDataJObject = null;

string oldData = string.Empty;
JObject oldDataJObject = null;


 newData="{"RECORDS":[{"ENGINE":"JZMBVB23034","CHASSIS":"MD2DSJZZZVWB78384","PRODH":"DISCOVER","LANDX":"BANGLADESH","AUART":"ZVEX","WADAT_IST":null},{"ENGINE":"PFZWJL61018","CHASSIS":"","PRODH":"BOXER","LANDX":"EGYPT","AUART":"ZVKP","WADAT_IST":null},{"ENGINE":"JZMBVB23035","CHASSIS":"MD2DSJZZZVWB78384","PRODH":"DISCOVER","LANDX":"BANGLADESH","AUART":"ZVKP","WADAT_IST":null}]}"
 newDataJObject=JObject.Parse(newData);


 oldData="{"RECORDS":[{"ENGINE":"JZMB23034","CHASSIS":"MD2DSJZZVWB78384","PRODH":"DISCOVER","LANDX":"BANGLADESH","AUART":"ZVEX","WADAT_IST":null},{"ENGINE":"PFZW61018","CHASSIS":"","PRODH":"BOXER","LANDX":"EGYPT","AUART":"ZVKP","WADAT_IST":null}]}";
 oldDataJObject = JObject.Parse(oldData);




 bool result = JToken.DeepEquals(newDataJObject, oldDataJObject);

                    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();

                    returnString = CompareObjects(newDataJObject, oldDataJObject);

 private static StringBuilder CompareObjects(JObject source, JObject target)
        {
            StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> sourcePair in source)
            {
                if (sourcePair.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    if (target.GetValue(sourcePair.Key) == null)
                    {
                        returnString.Append("Key " + sourcePair.Key
                                            + " not found" + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    else if (target.GetValue(sourcePair.Key).Type != JTokenType.Object)
                    {
                        returnString.Append("Key " + sourcePair.Key
                                            + " is not an object in target" + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnString.Append(CompareObjects(sourcePair.Value.ToObject<JObject>(),
                            target.GetValue(sourcePair.Key).ToObject<JObject>()));
                    }
                }
                else if (sourcePair.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                {
                    if (target.GetValue(sourcePair.Key) == null)
                    {
                        returnString.Append("Key " + sourcePair.Key
                                            + " not found" + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnString.Append(CompareArrays(sourcePair.Value.ToObject<JArray>(),
                            target.GetValue(sourcePair.Key).ToObject<JArray>(), sourcePair.Key));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    JToken expected = sourcePair.Value;
                    var actual = target.SelectToken(sourcePair.Key);
                    if (actual == null)
                    {
                        returnString.Append("Key " + sourcePair.Key
                                            + " not found" + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!JToken.DeepEquals(expected, actual))
                        {
                            // todo:logic to get the difference here only

                            returnString.Append("Key " + sourcePair.Key + ": "
                                                + sourcePair.Value + " !=  "
                                                + target.Property(sourcePair.Key).Value
                                                + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnString;
        }
        private static StringBuilder CompareArrays(JArray source, JArray target, string arrayName = "")
        {
            var returnString = new StringBuilder();
            for (var index = 0; index < source.Count; index++)
            {

                var expected = source[index];
                if (expected.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    var actual = (index >= target.Count) ? new JObject() : target[index];
                    returnString.Append(CompareObjects(expected.ToObject<JObject>(),
                        actual.ToObject<JObject>()));
                }
                else
                {

                    var actual = (index >= target.Count) ? "" : target[index];
                    if (!JToken.DeepEquals(expected, actual))
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(arrayName))
                        {
                            returnString.Append("Index " + index + ": " + expected
                                                + " != " + actual + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            returnString.Append("Key " + arrayName
                                                + "[" + index + "]: " + expected
                                                + " != " + actual + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnString;
        }
```

now  the expected result what i want is to get only the changes in the array object like this ie

```
   {
        "ENGINE": "JZMBVB23035",
        "CHASSIS": "MD2DSJZZZVWB78384",
        "PRODH": "DISCOVER",
        "LANDX": "Bangladesh",
        "AUART": "ZVKP"
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Dev

Comment: Turn them into normal arrays and then just [find the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991452/how-do-i-get-the-differences-between-two-string-arrays-in-c). Trying to deal with it using jObjects is just making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can deserialize both Json and then compare the lists. For example,

```
public class RECORD
{
    public string ENGINE { get; set; }
    public string CHASSIS { get; set; }
    public string PRODH { get; set; }
    public string LANDX { get; set; }
    public string AUART { get; set; }
    public object WADAT_IST { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<RECORD> RECORDS { get; set; }
}
```

using the above data structure, we can deserialize as follows.

```
var newDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(newData);
var oldDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(oldData);
```

Now we can find the difference as follows

```
var result = newDataList.RECORDS.Except(oldDataList.RECORDS)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried the same    
var newDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(newData);
var oldDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(oldData);
var emo = newDataList.RECORDS.Except(oldDataList.RECORDS).ToList();
but emo is giving all the records(count 3) not filtering.

Comment: @Devanathan.S Wouldn't that be the expected output as well ? since the all records has changed when compared to old. For example, in the first record Engine has changed from "JZMB23034" to "JZMBVB23034". Similarly in others.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of above post and used InitializationKeysComparer class. then it works like charm

```
List<RECORDS> dataToInsert = objNewData.Except(objOldData, new InitializationKeysComparer()).ToList();

    public class InitializationKeysComparer : IEqualityComparer<RECORDS>
    {
        public bool Equals(RECORDS x, RECORDS y)
        {
            return (x.ENGINE.Trim().Equals(y.ENGINE.Trim()) && x.PRODH.Trim().Equals(y.PRODH.Trim())&& x.LANDX.Trim().Equals(y.LANDX.Trim()));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(RECORDS obj)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```